# Web scraping rule creation

Tags: python, mysql, database, parsing, web-scraping

I am on this page: http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/ps4/a?view=condensed

And I want to go into each item and get the Developer and Genre, but my code doesn't seem to work.

For example, I want to go into this page: http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-4/angry-birds-star-wars

Then leave it and continue through the rest doing the same and adding to a database. What can I change in my code to make it work? Right now the database is for the dev and genre is null but it gets the rest of the data so it's like it never enters parse_Game

Also I added print statements into parseGame and none of them print

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
import MySQLdb
import re
from string import lowercase

class MetacriticSpider(BaseSpider):
def start_requests(self):
    #iterate through ps4 pages
    for c in lowercase:
        for i in range(self.max_id):
            yield Request('http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/ps4/{0}?page={1}'.format(c, i), callback = self.parseps4)

    #gets the developer and genre of a game
def parseGame(self, response):

    print("Here")

    item = response.meta['item']

    db1 = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "andy", "metacritic")
    cursor = db1.cursor()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)   
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="product_wrap"]')
    items = []

    item['dev'] = site.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "summary_detail developer")]/span[1]/text()').extract()
    item['genre'] = site.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "summary_detail product_genre")]/span[1]/text()').extract()    

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ps4 (dev, genre) VALUES (%s,%s)",[item['dev'][0],item['genre'][0]])
    items.append(item)

    print item['dev']
    print item['genre']

def parseps4(self, response):
    #some local variables
    db1 = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "andy", "metacritic")
    cursor = db1.cursor()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)   
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="product_wrap"]')
    items = []

    #iterates through each site
    for site in sites:
        with db1:
            item = MetacriticItem()

            #sets the item
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_title")]/a/text()').extract()
            item['cscore'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_score brief_metascore")]/div[1]/text()').extract() 
            item['uscore'] = site.xpath('.//div/ul/li/span[contains(@class, "data textscore")]/text()').extract()
            item['release'] = site.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "stat release_date full_release_date")]/span[2]/text()').extract()

            #some processing to check if there is a score attached, if there is, it adds it to the database
            if ("tbd" in item['cscore'][0] and "tbd" not in item['uscore'][0]) or ("tbd" not in item['cscore'][0] and "tbd" in item['uscore'][0]) or ("tbd" not in item['cscore'][0] and "tbd" not in item['uscore'][0]):
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ps4 (title, criticalscore, userscore, releasedate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s, %s)",[(' '.join(item['title'][0].split())).replace("(PS4)","",1),item['cscore'][0],item['uscore'][0],item['release'][0]])
                items.append(item)

            itemLink = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_title")]/a/@href' ).extract()

            req = Request('http://www.metacritic.com' +  itemLink[0], callback = self.parseGame)
            req.meta['item'] = item
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put `yield` before the `Request('http://www.metacritic.com' +  itemLink[0], callback = self.parseGame)`.

Comment: @alecxe I tried this and it doesn't work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is at least one more problem. in `parseGame` `item` is not defined. You need to pass `item` from `parseps4` to `parseGame` in `meta`: see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.

Comment: @alecxe I updated my code with what I changed. I've obviously not done it correctly because its still not working

Comment: You are missing `yield req` at the end of `parseps4`.

Comment: @alecxe oh yeah sorry should of mentioned, I tried with yield in front of  Request, but when I do that it says req.meta does not have a attribute called meta. I tried remove yield but no luck

Comment: Could you add the class definition of your spider and import statements too so I can try out and debug locally?

Comment: @alecxe I did just there man. Thanks for helping. Let me know if you need some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in the code:

- meta argument should contain a dictionary `{'item': item}`
- `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated - use `Selector` instead
- I think you shouldn't do mysql inserts inside the spider - use Database Pipeline instead:

  - [Writing items to a MySQL database in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845839/writing-items-to-a-mysql-database-in-scrapy)
- you need to get the first item of `extract()` call and do `strip()` on it (this will help to have strings in the Fields, not lists and without leading and trailing spaces and newlines)

Here's the code without `mysql` related calls:

```
from string import lowercase

from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector

from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem


class MetacriticSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'metacritic'
    allowed_domains = ['metacritic.com']

    max_id = 1 # your max_id value goes here!!!

    def start_requests(self):
        for c in lowercase:
            for i in range(self.max_id):
                yield Request('http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/ps4/{0}?page={1}'.format(c, i), callback=self.parseps4)

    def parseGame(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        site = hxs.select('//div[@class="product_wrap"]')

        # get additional data!!!

        yield item

    def parseps4(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="product_wrap"]')
        for site in sites:
            item = MetacriticItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_title")]/a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item['cscore'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_score brief_metascore")]/div[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item['uscore'] = site.xpath('.//div/ul/li/span[contains(@class, "data textscore")]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item['release'] = site.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "stat release_date full_release_date")]/span[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()

            link = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "basic_stat product_title")]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield Request('http://www.metacritic.com/' + link, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parseGame)
```

It works for me - I see the yielded items from `parseGame()` on a console.

Make sure it yields items first, then see the `!!!` comments - fill these lines accordingly.

After that, if you see items on a console, try creating a database pipeline to write items to mysql.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help with this man appreciate you writing up all the code! I have tried this but I still can't see anything in console about parseGame.

I put print("Hello") in parseGame to see if it getting into it but its not printing anything. How can I make sure it yields items?

Comment: @AndyOHart hm, what if you put prints into `start_requests` and `parseps4` - do you see them?

Comment: yep I do see those ones. Prints titles in the ps4parse and just printed In Start in the start_requests.

Comment: @AndyOHart ok, thanks, one more test. Put `print(link)` before yielding the request - what does it look like? Can you open this url in a browser?

Comment: yeah that prints the title, userscore, criticalscore, releasedate. Just noticed that a print statement inside of ParseGame did actually print it was just blending in with the rest of the code

Comment: I got it working I just had to change the hxs.select

Thanks again for all the help man :)

Comment: actually just a small question sorry. In my parseps4 when i try print dev, it says :

   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\item.py", line 50, in __getitem__
     return self._values[key]
 exceptions.KeyError: 'dev'

How can I access it?

Comment: @AndyOHart I think you haven't set `item['dev']` before accessing it.

Comment: I was thinking that, just sure how I access it from the yield?
I assign them in parseGame but I'm assuming I have to assign it in parsePS4 alsO?

Comment: @AndyOHart well, the order is `start_requests`->`parsePS4` -> `parseGame`, as far as I understand.

Comment: ah yes it is but i also have other parse functions such as parseXBOX and parsePC that will need to use the parseGame method
Is there a way for me to set them inside the parsePS4 from the response of parseGame?

Comment: @AndyOHart basically, if you need to fill item fields from different pages, you just pass an item in the `meta` in the `Request` - it's a chain.

Comment: okay so with this bit meta={'item': item}, I'm passing the item I have been using and getting the [dev] and [genre] and setting them in parse game. However I cant seem to access those 2 from parsePS4, so I assume I have to use a response from the request to set [dev] and [genre]?

Comment: Since `item['dev']` and `item['genre']` are set in parseGame, after the `parsePS4` - you cannot access them in `parsePS4`. It is a chain, in `parsePS4` item is initialized, then goes with `Request` to `parseGame`, then whereever you want with the next `Request` until you `yield` it.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure how to proceed because I need several other parse functions to access parseGame also

Comment: @AndyOHart think about it as one-way tube: you cannot reverse it, you can only go straight to the exit.

Comment: Oh yeah I completely understand what you mean. I can access the other variables inside of parseGame. Its just originally I was adding to database in the parse methods so this will chnage that and I will have to figure out how to add the different platforms to the separate tables in the database from parse game

Comment: @AndyOHart yup, basically fill out item fields in the spider methods, yield the item in the last one. Then, the database pipeline should handle where to put this item.

Comment: this will make my code much nicer but im not sure how i can do it, because every title returned has the console name beside it for example, Battlefield 3 (PS4), and in each parse function I removed that specific thing depending on the function. In the Pipelines would you just have 1 method to add to the database or like 6? one for each table?

Comment: @AndyOHart well, you can for example have one table for everything, but with a `type` (or `console`) column that will vary depend on a console.

Comment: I managed to get it all working great man thanks, actually ended up removing around 300 lines of code because of your explanation so thanks :) ended up using the console string that was in the title to determine the table, and then remove the string before it was added in so it looked nicer. Basically 9 if statements

Comment: @AndyOHart great! consider transforming 9 ifs into dictionary.

Comment: @AndyOHart I mean, create a mapping: `console` -> `table name` and use dictionary lookup to get the table name by the console.

Comment: Oh right that would be a good way to go about it. I will look into that. Thanks for all your help once again :)