# Insert statement does not work for datatype mismatch

Tags: python, mysql, csv, scrapy

I am scraping data from a site using Scrapy and Python and storing the data in a csv file. Then I am trying to fetch values from the csv file and trying to store the values in a mysql database table. The insert statement is neither triggering error nor inserting any data to the database. I checked the data types of fields whose values are coming from the csv. all are strings. All the values stored in csv are in string format. That's why while storing the values in db, it's creating problem for all the datatypes except string/varchar. What should I do now? **Apart from varchar, I have columns of int(6) and timestamp datatypes in my database table.**

import csv
    import re
    import pymysql
    import sys

```
connection = pymysql.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = ".....", db = "city_details")       
cursor = connection.cursor ()

def insert_articles2(rows):
  rowcount = 0
  for row in rows:
    if rowcount!= 0:
       sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO articles2 (country, event_name, md5, date_added, profile_image, banner, sDate, eDate, address_line1, address_line2, pincode, state, city, locality, full_address, latitude, longitude, start_time, end_time, description, website, fb_page, fb_event_page, event_hashtag, source_name, source_url, email_id_organizer, ticket_url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" 
      cursor.execute = (sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27]))
    rowcount+=1
rows = csv.reader(open("items.csv", "r"))
insert_articles2(rows)
```

connection.commit()

### Table structure for table `articles2`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles2` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_image` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `banner` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `sDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `eDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `address_line1` mediumtext,
  `address_line2` mediumtext,
  `pincode` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `locality` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `full_address` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext CHARACTER SET utf16 NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_page` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_event_page` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_hashtag` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `source_url` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `email_id_organizer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_url` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `full_address` (`full_address`),
  KEY `full_address_2` (`full_address`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `event_name` (`event_name`),
  KEY `sDate` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate` (`eDate`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `event_name_2` (`event_name`),
  KEY `sDate_2` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate_2` (`eDate`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `locality` (`locality`),
  KEY `start_time` (`start_time`),
  KEY `start_time_2` (`start_time`),
  KEY `end_time` (`end_time`),
  KEY `id_3` (`id`),
  KEY `id_4` (`id`),
  KEY `event_name_3` (`event_name`),
  KEY `md5` (`md5`),
  KEY `sDate_3` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate_3` (`eDate`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
  KEY `start_time_3` (`start_time`),
  KEY `end_time_2` (`end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4182 ;
```

Comment: Code is important, please give us something that illustrates your problem so we can better understand your particular situation.

Comment: @tadman : full code added. plz see.

Comment: That's a big improvement, but as this relates to your CSV data, you may need to include a sample of that, too. Are you sure you're not trying to import a header row with text into a numerical column by accident?

Comment: @tadman : no. Moreover, I have checked the data types for all the fields of all the rows in the csv. In all cases I found it's string. Wat to do?

Comment: Unless you can give an example of a row you're trying to import that fails, it's a process of elimination. Start deleting stuff until it works, then put things back until it fails.

Comment: `Wat to do? ` Have you considered using any search engines as a start?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of this particular SQL related error, that is very likely depending on some data mismatch, I can strongly suggest to avoid the step of exporting to CSV and instead adding the [scrapy-mysql-pipeline](https://github.com/IaroslavR/scrapy-mysql-pipeline) , this will export your scraped items directly into a MySQL table and from there you can move the date easily to other tables or process it ...

If you can't use the pipeline and/or you want something more customizable then you can have a look at [this answer here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845839/writing-items-to-a-mysql-database-in-scrapy) and you'll find useful information on how to write your own custom mysql pipeline...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Am asking one more thing to you. If you see the table structure, the only int type is pincode. But what I am fetching from csv is string. That's why I explicitly converted my pincode to int with this: pin = int(pin). Still I am getting this error:
"TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str"
 
Can you tell me what's happening here?

Comment: @Deba for all the columns in the format you have %s specifier ... You need %d or %i ...

Comment: Actually I copied the code from an older file. Even despite using %d for pincode I got that error.