# How to use MYSql from xampp for python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, xampp, mysql-python

I am getting below error when I try to install MySQL client using the command "pip3 install mysqlclient".

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/l1/f1klm_s92g53c9v2p1vrdwg80000gn/T/pip-install-a0t6svmj/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/l1/f1klm_s92g53c9v2p1vrdwg80000gn/T/pip-install-a0t6svmj/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/l1/f1klm_s92g53c9v2p1vrdwg80000gn/T/pip-install-a0t6svmj/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 28, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
```

XAMPP version:- 7.2.3.0
Python:- 3.7

Can anybody help me to solve this error? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the MySQL-python package, type the following command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

To install the mysql-connector-python package, type the following command:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

To install the pymysql package, type the following command:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Code sample

```
hostname = 'localhost'
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
database = 'DBNAME'
def doQuery( conn ) :
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute( "SELECT fname, lname FROM employee" )
for firstname, lastname in cur.fetchall() :
    print firstname, lastname
print "Using MySQLdb…"
import MySQLdb
myConnection = MySQLdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
print "Using pymysql…"
import pymysql
myConnection = pymysql.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
print "Using mysql.connector…"
import mysql.connector
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure** you have at least tried these commands.

- `pip install mysql`
- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
- `pip install MySQL-Python`
- Commands are run a `root` or `sudo`.

If nothing has changed. One of these solutions might help:

1. Try running `which mysql_config` from bash. If it can't be found, run: `locate mysql_config`. The file path to the binary needs to be in the $PATH environment variable or specified in `setup.py` for the (what is now) missing module.
2. You could try installing different packages. There is: `mysql-connector-python` or `libmysqlclient-dev`. The `python-dev` *might* help.
3. Attempt to find the directory and files `mysql/bin`, `mysql_config`, and `MySQL-Python` and add their locations to $PATH.

EDIT: There are a couple solutions to try:

- `apt-get install python-mysqldb`
- Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
- Debian/Ubuntu (2018): `sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev`
- XAMPP (OP specified): `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`

Comment: As i have mentioned i have installed xampp and have mysql installed under xampp. I am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845839/writing-items-to-a-mysql-database-in-scrapy.

Comment: I am trying it with scrapy.

Comment: I assume you're running Debian/Linux? If so, you're missing the package. If you're running the latest distro (2018 >) then try `sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev`. Otherwise, `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`, should work just fine. :)

Comment: I am using mac 10.13

Comment: If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, it couldn't hurt to try `brew install mysql`. To install Homebrew, open up a terminal and run `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.

Comment: I can install it but i am trying to use the same version of mysql installed with xampp.

Comment: Then why not upgrade mysql that xampp is using? [Tutorial here](http://www.mynotebucket.com/update-mysql-under-xmpp/).

Answer (score 0):

I have M1 processor in mac, and it solves my problem:

Install brew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Install mysql with brew: `arch -arm64 brew install mysql`

Try install again with `pip install mysql`