# how to save scraped data in db?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, mysql-workbench

I m trying to save scraped data in db but got stuck,

first I have saved scraped data in csv file and using glob library to find newest csv and upload data of that csv into db-

I m not sure what i m doing wrong here plase find code and error 
i have created table yahoo_data in db with same column name as that of csv and my code output

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import MySQLdb
import os
import csv
import glob

class YahooScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoo_scrapper'
    allowed_domains = ['in.news.yahoo.com']
    start_urls = ['http://in.news.yahoo.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        news_url=response.xpath('//*[@class="Mb(5px)"]/a/@href').extract()
        for url in news_url:
            absolute_url=response.urljoin(url)
            yield Request (absolute_url,callback=self.parse_text)

    def parse_text(self,response):
        Title=response.xpath('//meta[contains(@name,"twitter:title")]/@content').extract_first()
        # response.xpath('//*[@name="twitter:title"]/@content').extract_first(),this also works
        Article= response.xpath('//*[@class="canvas-atom canvas-text Mb(1.0em) Mb(0)--sm Mt(0.8em)--sm"]/text()').extract()
        yield {'Title':Title,
               'Article':Article}

    def close(self, reason):
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)
        mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                               user='root',
                               passwd='prasun',
                               db='books')
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file)

        row_count = 0
        for row in csv_data:
            if row_count != 0:
                cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO yahoo_data (Title,Article) VALUES(%s, %s)', row)
            row_count += 1

        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

gettting this error

```
ana. It should be directed not to disrespect the Sikh community and hurt its sentiments by passing such arbitrary and uncalled for orders," said Badal.', 'The SAD president also "brought it to the notice of the Haryana chief minister that Article 25 of the constitution safeguarded the rights of all citizens to profess and practices the tenets of their faith."', '"Keeping these facts in view I request you to direct the Haryana Public Service Commission to rescind its notification and allow Sikhs as well as candidates belonging to other religions to sport symbols of their faith during all examinations," said Badal. (ANI)']}
2019-04-01 16:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-04-01 16:49:41 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (25 items) in: items.csv
2019-04-01 16:49:41 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method YahooScrapperSpider.close of <YahooScrapperSpider 'yahoo_scrapper' at 0x2c60f07bac8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\Desktop\scrapping\scrapping\spiders\yahoo_scrapper.py", line 44, in close
    cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO yahoo_data (Title,Article) VALUES(%s, %s)', row)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
2019-04-01 16:49:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 7985,
 'downloader/request_count': 27,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 27,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2148049,
 'downloader/response_count': 27,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 26,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 11, 19, 41, 350717),
 'item_scraped_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 53,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 26,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 27,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 27,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 27,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 27,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 11, 19, 36, 743594)}
2019-04-01 16:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

seems motivated by the lack of a sufficient number of arguments in the row you passed.

You can try to print the row, to understand what is going wrong.

Anyway, if you want to save scraped data to DB, I suggest to write a simple item pipeline, which exports data to DB, without passing through CSV.

For further information abuot item pipelines, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#topics-item-pipeline

You can found a useful example at [Writing items to a MySQL database in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845839/writing-items-to-a-mysql-database-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are passing list to the parameters that need to be mentioned by the comma

try to add asterix to 'row' var:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO yahoo_data (Title,Article) VALUES(%s, %s)', row)
```

to:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO yahoo_data (Title,Article) VALUES(%s, %s)', *row)
```