# How to get the scraped data shown in the MySQL database in the terminal?

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy, mysql-python

I'm trying to get the scraped data to show up in the MySQL database.I'm following a course but it's not working.

I made sure that the data (title, rating, upc, product_type) are in the same order as it is in the csv file.

Here's my code,

In the code editor:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import csv
import glob
import MySQLdb
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

def product_info(response, value):
    return response.xpath('//th[text()="' + value + '"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()[0]

class BooksSpider(Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        rating = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "star-rating")]/@class').extract()[0]
        rating = rating.replace('star-rating ', '')

        # product information data points
        upc = product_info(response, 'UPC')
        product_type = product_info(response, 'Product Type')

        yield{
        'title': title,
        'rating': rating,
        'upc': upc,
        'product_type': product_type,
        }

        def close(self, reason):
            csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                                   user='shay',
                                   passwd='foo',
                                   db='books_db')

            cursor = mydb.cursor()

            csv_data = csv.reader(file(csv_file))

            row_count = 0
            for row in csv_data:
                if row_count != 0:
                    cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, rating, upc, product_type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, $s)', row)
                row_count += 1

            mydb.commit()
            cursor.close()
```

In the terminal:

```
mysql -u shay -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE books_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE books_db;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE books_table(
    -> title VARCHAR(20), 
    -> rating VARCHAR(20),
    -> upc VARCHAR(20), 
    -> product_type VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM books_table;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM books_table;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The expected result is a table of the scraped data in the terminal.

I run the code and then run the second (SELECT * FROM books_table;) line, the table is supposed to show up but it's still an Empty set.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If the code is as showed here, I don’t think your MySQL code is ever called. It does not really matter, as you should be using a Scrapy pipeline anyway. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849394/939364. Also, for future StackOverflow questions, please have a careful look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: first you need to indent the code in the given class, second you need to show the code where this class is being used

Comment: @prashantrana this is the way it was written in the course. How do I show the code where the class is being used?

Comment: @Shay if using pycharm , then just  right click on class name and click on find usage , there you will find the module where it is used

Comment: @prashantrana Okay, thank you!

Comment: first: you have to correct indention. Now you have `close()` inside `parse()` so it is not direct method in `BooksSpider` and it may not be executed. Second: I'm not sure if scrapy save data in csv before `close()`. It may save it muche later - so you may not find the newest data. Third: I would split this in to separated programs/script. First could use `scrapy` to create `.csv`, second could get data from csv and save in mysql. For second script you can use `Python` or mysql tools - see [how to use SQL to import data from csv](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)